# Get all children of same object by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, oop

I need your help. I have next simple class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get class by ID and all children of the class that have ParentId same with ID of first class (and children of children)? I need to use LINQ filtration. Thanks for help!

Comment: pls show what you have tried so far

Comment: you could turn on lazy loading but keep in mind that that is a performance hit.

Comment: Try creating recursive method and get children until there are no children left

Comment: Please look for LINQ + hierarchy or recursion. This a frequently recurring question (no pun intended).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are two solutions that I could find. The first is using the recursive method on the server-side. But in this variant, you need each time request database for each level of hierarchy. The best solution is using Recursion in SQL. You need to do only one request to the database. I attach the link. https://medium.com/swlh/recursion-in-sql-explained-graphically-679f6a0f143b